# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl':

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please why am I having this error when I run my application

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.springfoundation.service.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
  No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined:
  expected single matching bean but found 3: 
  [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,
   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,
   org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
```

This is the second stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.springfoundation.service.SecurityServiceImpl.authenticationManager; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
  No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined:
  expected single matching bean but found 3: 
  [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,
   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,
   org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Somehow you registered  **Three** `AuthenticationManager`s. Post more details about your configurations..

Comment: Could you please post some of your code? What does your spring-servlet.xml file look like?

Comment: @AliDehghani Which section of the code are you looking for?

Comment: For starters, post your security related configurations .

Comment: @AliDehghani Can I paste this code using pastebin.com

Comment: It would be better if you post them here but you can post them there too.

Comment: This is for my spring-security-config.xml http://pastebin.com/f5pfmX4n

Comment: This is for my main-dispatcher-servlet.xml http://pastebin.com/pLr6RTri

Comment: this is for my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  http://pastebin.com/8Rfi7ymw

Answer (score 0):

the exception above means that you may forgot to define a bean, that implements your DAO interface.

```
<bean id="object name" class="com.java.model.FirstModelImple" />
```

Comment: in your xml configuration

Comment: check the comment nd you will see all my xml configuration

Comment: check this tutorial: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html